# Official word on whether all Seinfeld episodes have reference to Superman?

Tags: reference, seinfeld

There are quite a few web pages on the Internet that discuss whether or not a Superman reference can be found in every single episode of Seinfeld.

Has anyone affiliated with the show ever made a statement on whether or not every episode contains a Superman reference?  Apparently the extras on some of the Seinfeld DVDs mention this topic, but I found a couple of conflicting comments from people regarding the DVDs:

[One person says](http://dan.hersam.com/2010/07/10/setting-the-superman-seinfeld-record-straight/#comment-151249):

> If you purchase the DVD they actually say in the extras that there is in fact a Visible reference to superman or they discuss superman but yes it is in every episode and sometimes it is a reach.

[Another person says](http://www.tv.com/shows/seinfeld/forums/did-you-know-225-588496/):

> It is said a few times on some of the DVDs that not every episode contains a Superman reference.

Do some of the DVDs really say one thing while other DVDs say the opposite?

Comment: If you count the fact that Jerry has a Superman doll on his shelf, then yes every episode has a Superman reference lol

Comment: I've seen Superman on Jerrys refrigerator

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know about anyone affiliated with the show, but [Barry Freiman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Freiman) (d. 2012) has discussed this. He was a freelance writer who, among other things, was a Superman guru, reporting and contributing to many of the Superman fan sites, e.g. [Superman Homepage](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/news.php) and [Superboy Homepage](http://www.superboyhomepage.com/).

He wrote an [article on the Superman Homepage](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/tv/tv.php?topic=articles/seinfeld) where he stated:

> Almost everyone knows that comedian Jerry Seinfeld is a big Superman
>   fan. But an urban legend has sprung up that Jerry snuck a reference to
>   the Man of Steel in every episode of NBC's Must-See comedy juggernaut,
>   "Seinfeld", which aired from 1989 to 1998. Not true.
>
> Thanks to my TIVO, I've taken a ride around the syndication wheel of
>   "Seinfeld" repeats on TBS over the past few months, screening the
>   episodes for Superman references. As it turns out...[despite many appearances] it's still far from something super snuck into
>   every episode.

On the article, he does include a link to every episode which contains a Superman reference.

Now, whilst this isn't the completely conclusive answer you were after, given Freiman's prominence in the Superman world, I think his opinion on the subject does carry substantial weight and thus I would say: **no, not every Seinfeld episode contains Superman references**.

**Edit:**

Okay, some definitive proof. Interview with Jerry Seinfeld, in July 2014, conducted on [Reddit](http://interviewly.com/i/jerry-seinfeld-jul-2014-reddit):

> **[Question]** There is a rumor that there is a Superman reference in every episode
>   of Seinfeld. Can you confirm or deny this and who's idea was it to put
>   the references in the show?
>
> **[Jerry]** I can deny it categorically. You can't count seeing the little
>   Superman model on the bookshelf as a Superman reference. I would say
>   there are maybe 10 Superman references out of a whole 180 or so
>   episodes, so that's a long way from all of them.

Peter Mehlman, a writer for Seinfeld, [also comments](http://parade.com/20772/petermehlman/a-writer-for-the-sitcom-explains-why-seinfeld-loved-superman/):

> Contrary to rumor, it was never planned to make the Man of Steel a
>   recurring theme, and the writing staff, on which I worked for six
>   seasons, *never got an edict dictating regular mentions of him*.

Whilst this certainly isn't as categorical a denial as Jerry Seinfeld provides, it does show that the writers were certainly not instructed or primarily interested in dropping these references - rather it was just an entertaining side project that happened occasionally, with the fans taking it to whole new levels (e.g. if Jerry wears red and blue, fans of the theory consider that a link).

Comment: The problem is that syndicated episodes will have bits cut out, and it is possible that a Superman reference was made and was cut out on TBS.

Comment: @pacoverflow: Perhaps, but I don't feel it's likely that the MANY episodes of Superman shown on TBS all just happened to cut out the Superman references. That seems far too contrived.

Comment: Two downvotes? Really? I thought this was pretty good.

Comment: I was really looking for something from an official source.  Perhaps Barry Freiman was looking for the obvious references, but other people on the internet say that the episodes without an obvious reference may have much more subtle references.

Comment: @pacoverflow: Okay, amended

Comment: Thanks, I removed my downvote.  Jerry's quote is interesting, since he says "You can't count seeing the little Superman model on the bookshelf".  But the whole idea that a lot of episodes contain a Superman reference comes primarily from that model on the bookshelf being in so many episodes.  I think your quote from Peter Mehlman is much more helpful.

Comment: @pacoverflow: If you look at a few of the blogs online, you actually get some interesting findings. Anything remotely related to Superman, no matter how small, counts. For example, I've seen fans claim that the episode in the parkign lot where Kramer holds the air conditioner is Superman-esque, since it would be heavy. That's taking things to too far in my opinion.

Comment: @pacoverflow - People on the internet will bend anything to fit whatever agenda they are pushing.

Comment: My thought for obvious episodes where Superman would not appear were the India episodes.  Can anyone confirm that these did not have Superman in them?

Comment: It would seem the episode(s) in India would be an easy example used to disprove this.  In fact, I just watched the last 15 minutes of one of them.  I didn't see Superman, but also didn't see the beginning.